# Postgresql huge remote connections raise "connection to server at "host",port 5432 failed Connection timout Is the server accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: postgresql, server, tcp, psycopg2, remote-server

I created database on separated server, and i have another remote three servers that connected with the database, i have huge connections that occurred in same time from those three servers, many of them can finish the query successfully but sometimes  raise error "connection to server at "000.000.000.000", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?"

Comment: or use the other 'servers' `external ip` also you will need to configure remote database access

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen "connection to server at `000.000.000.000, port 5432` that means the database server  ip and port like this example `162.156.458.423:5432`, I don't put the real ip server in the post to just security but the port is real

Comment: What is 'huge connections'.  Number? duration? bytes of throughput?  Please quantify.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen 0.0.0.0 will certainly not work as a connect target *at all,* and 127.0.0.1 will only work if the DBMS is running in the local host, which it isn’t in this question.

Comment: @jjanes  80 connection per server that mean 240 connection occurred concurrently on the three servers.                                                                                                                every one connection of the 80 can insert with query (bulk insert) 2634500 bytes that means 80 * 2634500 = 210760000 bytes concurrently per server, finally that means 210760000 * 3 bytes inserted on three servers concurrently.

Comment: @user207421 thats clearly reply thanks.

Comment: "connection timed out" is generally a problem with a firewall.  But if it happens only occasionally, that seems unlikely.  Maybe the network is just being overwhelmed, or you are triggering some kind of DDoS protection.  Basically, it is networking problem.

Comment: @jjanes  i have searched about the problem and i changed many times in postgres.conf file but it's useless.                                                                                                        What about async/await connection ?

Comment: I think you need to look at your networking hardware and configuration.  Not PostgreSQL.